# Turn specific error into a failure in ruby Test::Unit

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, inheritance, testunit

I would like a way to take an error generated within a specific test method inside a Test::Unit::TestCase and turn it into a failure with a more friendly generic message.  I keep thinking this should be possible with some inheritance but I can't quite get my head around it.

```
class CalenderTest001 < Test::Unit::TestCase
  def testZoneCal001
    Fixture.reset
    $driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox
    $driver.get "http://myTestSite.com/"
    $driver.find_element(:id, "IDthrowsAnError").click
  end
end
```

The effect I would like is to have the entire thing wrapped in a begin rescue end block with the rescue block looking something like this.

```
rescue Selenium::WebDriver::Error::NoSuchElementError => e
  #mark this test as a failure not an error
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [assert_nothing_raised](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/test/unit/rdoc/Test/Unit/Assertions.html#method-i-assert_nothing_raised) construct:

```
def testZoneCal001
  assert_nothing_raised "Something went wrong!" do
    Fixture.reset
    $driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox
    $driver.get "http://myTestSite.com/"
    $driver.find_element(:id, "IDthrowsAnError").click
  end
end
```

Comment: I would like to make the test case and the test report more readable to people who didn't write the test.  I would need to catch that specific error, and it would help if I didn't actually have to wrap every single test in a do end block.  It seems like there should be a way to DRY this out.